# How to get font name from a file?

Tags: c++, winapi

I've been using `GetFontResourceInfoW` to get font name from font file, but turns out it's not robust and often fails. This function works most of time if font is in the system fonts folder.

I need to get the font name without installing it. If font file is a collection of styles then I need the names of fonts in this collection.

Arial, Arial Black, Arial Italic etc. ..

I've looked into `PrivateCollection`  of GDI+ but it doesn't support font files like `.fon` and `.fnt` and DirectWrite is worse. The legacy GDI supports all formats, but I can't find a function capable doing what I looking for.

Is there any other API I could use to accomplish this?

Comment: DirectWrite is the official (not super simple, ok) way. What doesn't work exactly with it? https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/master/Samples/DirectWriteCustomFontSets

Comment: @SimonMourier It doesn't supports .fon and .fnt types. See the table on bottom of this page, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdiplus/-gdiplus-creating-a-private-font-collection-use

Comment: Hmm. Maybe a bad comment on my part.